# Status Thread only report when other threads pull from Queue

Tags: java, multithreading

Im using a LinkedBlockingQueue, shared by several worker threads and 1 status reporter thread.

The status reporter thread reports, every 30 seconds, how many items are left in the queue:

```
while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            try {
                float completion = (queue.size() * 1.0f) / this.queueSize;
                System.out.println(this.jobeName+" : "+this.conferenceYear+ " remaining..."+MessageFormat.format("{0,number,#.##%}",completion));
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30);;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to get the status thread to only report when a worker thread has pulled from the queue?

Comment: you mean, when ever worker thread has pulled from the queue you want status thread to report and not wait for 30 is secs?

Comment: You can check when this number has changed and only print it when it does.

Comment: @PeterLawrey there may be a situation when one thread pulled and another pushed--size will remain the same.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou it is possible but very unlikely unless the length is zero, which it should be most of the time. Note: the queue length doesn't include any jobs actually running.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu exactly!

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm only pulling, not pushing.

Comment: @MichaelClayton Simpler solution would be to let the worker threads invoke a method on the statusThread directly after they pull from the queue, unless I am missing something. With this statusThread would be just an object need not run as a seperate thread.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu I thought about that. but I dont want my workers to do anything other than work. I am starting to think this may not be worth my time.

Comment: @MichaelClayton It can be done using thread notification mechanism (posted as answer below) but it would definitely be more complex than directly calling the method on status Thread. I doubt if it is worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpler solution would be to let the `worker threads` invoke a method on the `statusThread` directly after they pull the task from the queue. With this `statusThread` would be just an object and need not run as a separate thread.

However if you want to have this manage through threads notification mechanism, it can be done but definitely not as simpler a solution than above and more synchronization overhead.

Approach could be -

We can use `wait` and `notify` mechanisms.

`Status thread` would continuously `wait` on `object A` monitor. And whenever it gets `notify` call from `worker threads` it prints the stats. (Note that we need to take care of spurious wake scenario here).

On the other hand, `Worker threads` while picking the task from the queue would acquire a lock on `object B` and after picking up the task would call the `notify` method on `object A` (by acquiring a lock on `object A`) and finally releases the lock on `object B` for next `worker thread` to pick up the task from queue.